# I have a Printek bluetooth printer that can pair with my mobile but bluetooth scanning apps don't recognise it

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a Printek FP-541 bluetooth printer which I can pair with my Android mobile using the native bluetooth scanner and using the Printek app can print to it so I know that it works.

I am writing an app and need to get the UUID, so I installed Lightblue along a few other bluetooth scanner apps but the printer does not show up in the scan.  I found one bluetooth scanner that works but it does not give details on the UUID.

What else can I try?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Printek FP-541 works over classic Bluetooth and not Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). This is why an app like LightBlue or nRF Connect would not be able to find it. Usually printers that work over classic Bluetooth support the Serial Port Profile (SPP) or the Basic Printing Profile (BPP). That being said, this printer could be supporting a custom profile that was developed by the vendor specifically for their products. The only ways to find out are to either contact the manufacturer or try to reverse engineer this yourself. If you go for the latter, I recommend downloading an SPP or BPP Android app as a starting point to see if the printer supports these profiles.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Will give them a try!!